# Lower Minimum Screen Brightness

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight

By using `/sys/class/backlight/` the screen brightness can go lower than when using the function keys to do so.

Is there a way to change the minimum level used by the function key method, rather than having to manually write to the file each time?

Answer (score 0):

you can use xbacklight and set a custom shortcut using your brightness down key to use xbacklight.
You can do that as follows
run the following command in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Under system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> custom shortcuts add the following custom shortcut.

```
xbacklight -[percentage]
```

Replacing [percentage] with a number. I would suggest 5.

---

A different way to do it is using [Oblitum](https://github.com/oblitum/backlight). 
This program will change the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file for you.
To install it follow these instructions

run `go get github.com/oblitum/backlight`

the tool is the single generated executable installed under $GOPATH/bin.

There's a .desktop file that should be copied to ~/.local/share/applications/ and a corresponding svg icon that should be copied to ~/.local/share/icons/backlight/.

Please, edit the .desktop file with a text editor for setting the correct icon path. This must be a fully expanded path.

There's a backlight.sh script to relax file permissions of the backlight system files. It should be copied to /etc/init.d/ and after that the command `sudo update-rc.d -f backlight.sh defaults 99` should be executed for registering the script to execute on boot.

I hope this helps although it's a bit late